# Trace LINQ when Joins are used

Tags: c#, linq

[Note After Answer: I am actually querying in memory-objects and that's why `ToTraceString` doesn't work. I added this to save the reader potential time from reading my long post].

I'm using a `ToTraceString` command when trying to inspect how my LINQ queries end up looking. However, today my query got a bit complicated, involving a `join` and all of the sudden, I get this error when I try to Trace my String:

Unable to cast object of type 'd__7a`1[EGSLanguageProviderShared.DTODataType]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.

My Query, and subsequent invocation of `ToTraceString` is as follows (note that System.Data.Entity has to be referenced in order for this to work). Both objects I'm querying (langDTs and langInstructionsAVDTs) are Entity Framework (.Net 3.5) objects from the same database. My Where Clause (== av.InstructionAVKey) uses a simple Value Collection Class, nothing to see there.

```
      IEnumerable<DTODataType> dts = 
          (from langDT in langDTs 
          join langIAVDT in langInstructionsAVDTs 
          on langDT.DataTypeKey equals langIAVDT.DataTypeKey 
          where langIAVDT.InstructionAVKey == av.InstructionAVKey 
          select langDT).Distinct();
      var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)dts).ToTraceString();
```

Any ideas on how I could see the LINQ translation of this Join? ::- ). I noticed that System.Data.Objects has more types of queries, but I can't get any of the ones which seem more relevant to this case, to work.

**LATER EDIT:**

As you recommended, I tried changing the IEnumerable to an IQueryable but that resulted in a type incompatibility compilation error ::- /.

After doing an explicit cast, I got the same error, but at Runtime (`Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>d__7a1[EGSLanguageProviderShared.DTODataType]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[EGSLanguageProviderShared.DTODataType]'.`)

Additional code: my objects langDTs and langInstructionsAVDTs are:

```
List<DTOInstructionActiveValueDataType> langInstructionsAVDTs = CurrentLPInstructionManager.GetInstructionsActiveValuesDataTypes((from avKey in langInstructionsAVs select avKey.InstructionAVKey).Distinct().ToArray());

List<DTODataType> langDTs = _LPDataTypeManager.GetDataTypes((from dt in langInstructionsAVDTs orderby dt.DataTypeKey select dt.DataTypeKey).Distinct().ToArray());
```

So these objects are indeed queried immediately because they are Lists ::- ). As for DTODataType and DTOInstructionActiveValueDataType, they are simple Value Collection Classes, just public Properties, that's all.

**EVEN LATER EDIT**

Might be of interest that at their root, the objects I'm using are indeed declared as ObjectQuery back in the deepest layer (Entity Framework):

```
public global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<instructions> instructions
```

However, as I bring the data from over the Data Access Layer, I am converting them to Data Transfer Objects (the DTO-prefixed classes you keep seeing), which are simple Value Collection Classes (a property-by-property map of the Entity Objects which I use in order to keep the Data Model completely separated from the View and also to execute any data post-processing in the Presentation side).

Comment: i usually use LINQPAD for this purpose.. it has a nice feature that does this..(click on lambda icon in results pane)

Comment: see my edit - need a bit more code in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Adam. I added a note as well, hopefully not wasting anybody's time with this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your subsequent edit, it's clear that you are simply querying and joining *in memory* collections.  That's why you can't cast to `ObjectQuery`, and that's also why you can't declare the query to be of type `IQueryable<T>`.

In other words there's no way to do a dump of the SQL being issued, because no SQL is being issued.  Once you converted your data over to your in-memory collection of DTOs, you became disconnected from your database, and all your queries became linq-to-objects queries with no corresponding T-SQL being generated.

Comment: Ummm... sorry for getting you worked up about this then ::- ). Does this mean there is no way of somehow finding what's going on when I'm querying those objects? I was trying to see why I get a certain result in a certain case, and I needed a way to see where the data is coming from. Like a "Stack Trace" but for LINQ. Ok, yes, I am querying in-memory collections, but is there a way to see exactly how the collections are being formed in a single command?

Comment: Worked up?  I had a lot of fun answering this :)  As to your new question, I don't know.  Post a new question asking that specifically and hopefully there's a linqto-objects expert who can help you (there probably is)  Please also post a link to the question here; I'm interested in the answer myself.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of typing your variable as `IEnumerable<DTODataType>` try `IQueryable<DTODataType>`, or even var.

I'm guessing somewhere in there your query is getting executed, and the results being stored as `IEnumerable`, and therefore no longer able to be cast as `ObjectQuery`

**EDIT**

Can you please expand your code snippet to show were both langDTs and langInstructionsAVDTs come from?

Comment: Bingo!  Because he's declared it as an IEnumerable the ORM is executing the query straight away.  The result isn't an ObjectQuery and cannot be cast to an ObjectQuery and therefore cannot call ToTraceString.

Comment: Are you sure?  I just tested a query that was declared as IEnumerable<T>, and it didn't run the query in either L2S, OR EF4.  I'm guessing his query is executing *somewhere*, but I don't think it's because he declared it as IEnumerable.  I'd be interested to see what langDTs and landInstructionsAVDTs are.  Are *they* declared as IEnumerable??

Comment: In entity framework if you assign a query comprehension to an IEnumerable the query gets executed immediately.  I assume he's using EF because he's using ObjectQuery.  I've only used it in EF1 though, maybe they've changed the behaviour in EF4.

Comment: That sentence made me realise just how silly the version naming for EF actually is.

Comment: Hello and thanks for answering! ::- ). I cannot type the variable as IQueryable. I get a "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<EGSLanguageProviderShared.DTODataType>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<EGSLanguageProviderShared.DTODataType>'." Error. If I try to Explicitly cast it, then I get a runtime error: Unable to cast object of type '<DistinctIterator>d__7a`1[EGSLanguageProviderShared.DTODataType]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[EGSLanguageProviderShared.DTODataType]'. @DoctaJonez: Entity Framework versioning is weird. They jumped a lot of versions ::- D.

Comment: @DoctaJonez - I think hey're fixed EF4 - the behavior you describe (fortunately) no longer seems to be present.  Typing a query as IEnumerabe<T> no longer causes the query to execute immediately, but can cause huge problems later, like if you call Count() (which will execute the original query, then count the number of rows returned, instead of issuing a select count(*)